# I have a javascript object, and I want to find a user by id and update their balance

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

```
var leaderboard = [{userId: 10293, balance: 1023},
                   {userId: 20394, balance: 1806},
                   {userId: 45333, balance: 2064},
                   {userId: 57456, balance: 2453},
                   {userId: 24575, balance: 2703}
                  ];
```

I have this object and want to create a function that searches to see if a user is already added by checking all the `userId`s. If they do exist I want to update their specific balance to a new one, in my case it will be `msg.userBalance`. If they don't exist I want to check if their balance is greater than any one of the balances currently in the object, and if so I want to add them to it and remove the 6th one with the lowest balance.

```
leaderboard.map(function(person) {
  if (person.userId == msg.userId) {
    person.balance = msg.userBalance
  } else {
    if (currentBalance > //other 5 balances in object { 
      leaderboard.push({userId: msg.userId, balance: msg.userBalance});
    }
  }
});
```

I'm a bit stuck and I know I'm in the right direction but obviously missing a big part of the equation. I'm not opposed to using jQuery I'm just looking for the most simple solution. Help?

Comment: Does the console throw an error?

Comment: That doesn't sound like a good use case for `.map`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will do what you want,,

```
var user = leaderboard.filter(function(user){return userId == msg.userId})[0];
if(user){
   user.balance = msg.userBalance;
} else {
   leaderboard.push({userId: msg.userId, balance: msg.userBalance});
   leaderboard.sort(function(a,b){return a.balance-b.balance});
   leaderboard.shift();     
}
```

what i did here is ,, I used **filter** to get the user that matches your target user id ,,
and if it wasn't found ,, I add it to the array ,, and then sort the array ascending ,, and then remove the first element ,, which will be the lowest one

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you so much. Thanks everyone else as well.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the most efficient, but it's late and I'm tired.

```
var lowest = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY;             // set the lowest value to something really high
$.each(leaderboard, function(idx,item){            // get the lowest value
    if(item.balance < lowest){
        lowest = item.balance;
    }
});

var i = $.grep(leaderboard, function(item){        // get the item based on userId, if it already exists
    return item.userId == msg.userId;
})[0];

if(!i){                                                     // if it doesnt exist...
    if(msg.userBalance > lowest){                           // if the new items balance is greater than the lowest one
        leaderboard.push(msg);                              // add it
        leaderboard = $.grep(leaderboard, function(item){   // and remove the item with the lowest value from the array
            return item.balance != lowest;
        });
    }
} else {                                           // if it does exists
    i.balance = msg.userBalance;                   // update the balance
}
```

[Here's a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/fotudv8w/1/).

It's probably possible to get it working the way you've started out - I've just never been a fan of $.map, for no reason in particular. This solution is just one of many dozen ways it *could* be done, and might help give you an idea about the logic required.

Answer (score 0):

The solution passes through the array at a time. But we need to go through once in the beginning to initialize the value of the subsidiary.

```
    leaderboard.max = -Infinity; // Set max balance
    leaderboard.min = Infinity; // Set min balance
    leaderboard.forEach( function( item, index, self ) {
        if (item.balance>self.max) self.max = item.balance;
        if (item.balance<self.min) self.min = item.balance;    
    });

    leaderboard.updateBalance = function ( userId, newBalance ) {
        var updated = false;
        var minIndex1 = -Infinity;
        var minIndex2 = Infinity;
        this.forEach( function( item, index, self ) {

            // Find 2 index with minimal balance
            if (item.balance === self.min) minIndex1 = index;
            if (item.balance > self.min && item.balance < minIndex2) minIndex2 = index;

            // If find user - update balance and min and max
            if (item.userId === userId) {
                updated = true; // Flag - user balance updated
                self[index].balance = newBalance;
                if (newBalance > self.max) self.max = newBalance;
                if (newBalance < self.min) self.min = newBalance;            
            }
        });

        // No user find? Push
        if (!updated && newBalance > leaderboard.max) {
            this.min = this[minIndex2].balance;
            if (this.length===5) this.splice(minIndex1, 1); // Remove user with minimal balance
            this.max = newBalance;
            this.push( { userId: userId, balance: newBalance } );
        }
    };
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5cfyLodp/

Answer (score 0):

You might like to consider restructuring your list of objects as a hash table.
It has all the makings of a good one, as your objects are just key-value pairs.

Then you can more powerfully and simply refer to your balances by their keys to achieve what you're after.

```
// Initialise hash table
var leaderboard = {
    {10293, 1023}
    {20394, 1806},
    {45333, 2064},
    {57456, 2453},
    {24575, 2703}
};

// Initialise person and msg somewhere

// If the person exists already, update their balance
if(leaderboard[person.userId] != null) {
    leaderboard[person.userId] = msg.userBalance;
    return; // Return early, we've done our work
}

// If the person's balance is greater than any of the others in the hash, replace them
for(var i in leaderboard) {
    if(leaderboard[i] < msg.userBalance) {
        delete leaderboard[i];
        leaderboard[person.userId] = msg.userBalance
    }
}
```